# Importing a File Into Tailwind.Config.JS

Tags: javascript, require, tailwind-css

I am getting started with Tailwindcss.  I want to override the default tailwind color palette with the material-design color palette.  I can easily just cut and paste all the material design palette into the `tailwind.config.js` file and everything works fine.  I.e., like this:

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      transparent: "transparent",
      black: "#000000",
      white: "#FFFFFF",

      "red-50": "#FFEBEE",
      "red-100": "#FFCDD2",
      "red-200": "#EF9A9A",
      "red-300": "#E57373",
      "red-400": "#EF5350",
      "red-500": "#F44336",
      "red-600": "#E53935",
      "red-700": "#D32F2F",
      "red-800": "#C62828",
      "red-900": "#B71C1C",
      "red-a100": "#FF8A80",
      "red-a200": "#FF5252",
      "red-a400": "#FF1744",
      "red-a700": "#D50000",

      ...
    },
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

The only problem is that the material design color palette object is rather large -- so I would rather save it as a separate file and import (or `require`) it into the `tailwind.config.js` file.  Something like this:

```
// material-palette.js
const colors = {
      transparent: "transparent",
      black: "#000000",
      white: "#FFFFFF",

      "red-50": "#FFEBEE",
      "red-100": "#FFCDD2",
      "red-200": "#EF9A9A",
      "red-300": "#E57373",
      "red-400": "#EF5350",
      "red-500": "#F44336",
      "red-600": "#E53935",
      "red-700": "#D32F2F",
      "red-800": "#C62828",
      "red-900": "#B71C1C",
      "red-a100": "#FF8A80",
      "red-a200": "#FF5252",
      "red-a400": "#FF1744",
      "red-a700": "#D50000",

      ...
    }

// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require("./material-palette");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors,
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

But this does not work.  I also tried to use the `spread operator` for the colors object, like this:

```
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require("./material-palette");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    ...colors,
    extend: {}
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};
```

But this also did not work.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you should add a `module.exports = colors` line to your `material-palette.js`.

Answer (score 2):

I replicate your code. Since we both are searching for the same answer.
I was able to get it working by this way

```
// tailwind.config.js
const colors = require('./material-palette');

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors,
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: []
};



// ./material-palette.js
module.exports = {
  'red-50': '#FFEBEE'
  'red-a100': '#FF8A80'
  ...THE REST OF PALETTE
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer above is correct, but to be more clear (works with Tailwind 2.x):

tailwind.config.js

```
const colors = require('./your-colors');

module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: colors, // instead of just Colors
        }
    }
}
```

and

your-colors.js eg

```
module.exports = {
            gray: {
                '50':  '#FAFCFC',
                '100': '#E4E8EE',
                '200': '#C1C9D0',
                '300': '#A2ABB7',
                '400': '#8892A2',
                '500': '#6B7385',
                '600': '#505669',
                '700': '#3C4055',
                '800': '#2B2E44',
                '900': '#2B2E44',
            },
            blue: {
                '50':  '#F5FCFF',
                '100': '#D9EDFF',
                '200': '#ACCFFC',
                '300': '#85ACF4',
                '400': '#758CEC',
                '500': '#5C66D2',
                '600': '#414AA6',
                '700': '#313B84',
                '800': '#262C62',
                '900': '#152041',
            },
            teal: {
                '50':  '#EEFDFE',
                '100': '#CFF3FB',
                '200': '#8ED8E9',
                '300': '#62BDE4',
                '400': '#4D9DCE',
                '500': '#277FB5',
                '600': '#1C5B92',
                '700': '#154876',
                '800': '#0F3451',
                '900': '#082530',
            },
            emerald: {
                '50':  '#F2FEEE',
                '100': '#CFF7C9',
                '200': '#91E396',
                '300': '#52D080',
                '400': '#3EB574',
                '500': '#288D60',
                '600': '#216B44',
                '700': '#18533A',
                '800': '#113B34',
                '900': '#0A2627',
            },
            orange: {
                '50':  '#FBF9EA',
                '100': '#F6E4BA',
                '200': '#E7C07B',
                '300': '#DC9742',
                '400': '#CB7519',
                '500': '#AD5102',
                '600': '#893301',
                '700': '#6C2706',
                '800': '#501A0F',
                '900': '#361206',
            },
            chestnut: {
                '50':  '#FEFAEE',
                '100': '#FCE2C0',
                '200': '#EFB586',
                '300': '#E78B5F',
                '400': '#D7664B',
                '500': '#B34434',
                '600': '#912728',
                '700': '#731620',
                '800': '#550F1C',
                '900': '#3B0B14',
            },
            cerise: {
                '50':  '#FEF7F4',
                '100': '#FBE0DD',
                '200': '#F2AFB3',
                '300': '#EC798B',
                '400': '#DC5472',
                '500': '#BC3263',
                '600': '#98184D',
                '700': '#73123F',
                '800': '#560E39',
                '900': '#3B0427',
            },
            purple: {
                '50':  '#FEF7FF',
                '100': '#F8DDF4',
                '200': '#E8ADE1',
                '300': '#D882D9',
                '400': '#BF62CF',
                '500': '#9B47B2',
                '600': '#743095',
                '700': '#57237E',
                '800': '#3D1867',
                '900': '#2A0D53',
            },
            indigo: {
                '50':  '#F8F9FE',
                '100': '#E7E5FC',
                '200': '#C6C0E9',
                '300': '#AE9DDE',
                '400': '#9B7AD8',
                '500': '#7F58BE',
                '600': '#5F4199',
                '700': '#4A2D7F',
                '800': '#362164',
                '900': '#20144C',
            },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the key `colors` also.

So `colors: colors` in your case

```
module.exports = {
    theme: {
        extend: {
            colors: colors, // instead of just Colors
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: From ES6+, `colors: colors` is the same as `colors`.